# What to do when the ISP seems to interrupt a SOCKS5 connection to a VPS?

Tags: proxy, socks-proxy, vps, socks5

I have a VPS and until now have been using a socks5 server on it.

The problem is that recently my ISP (I live in Iran) has figured out some way to interrupt it and I'm receiving the "blocked page" for websites which are censored even through the proxy service. I know in some way that the problem isn't with the VPS, it's located in Germany and when used with other ISPs there's no problem.

What is causing the problem? Isn't the socks5 connection secure? What are the alternatives?

Comment: can you `ssh -D 9999` to your vps and use the localhost:9999 as the socks-proxy? http://support.suso.com/supki/SSH_Tutorial_for_Linux#SOCKS5_proxying

Comment: on Windows, any ways to do so? can be done with putty?

Comment: @Nig: Yes, it can be done with PuTTY, *if* you can SSH the VPS.

Comment: @Nig: http://martinjr.net/2010/06/29/quick-and-easy-socks5-ssh-tunnel-set-up-with-putty/

Comment: @akira thanks, worked but the speed is not satisfying.

Comment: I suggest to use ShadowSocks. I'm living in China mainland and also fighting with the national firewall.

Answer (score 3):

Socks handshake is transparent and easy to detect(3 bytes static data). A DPI can monitor the packet data to detect the socks connection.
To evade the detection you may need to customize the handshake by changing the original socks protocol both at client and server.
By default, the client initiates the connection with these bytes(if no auth)

> ### 0x05, 0x01, 0x00
>
> 5 define the socks version, 1 represents the no of methods, 0 the method type
>   One quick hack is to change the client to send
>
> ### 0x05, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
>
> Now the signature gets changed and DPI may fail to detect. (Here we says there are 3 methods, but we send redundant method, so no changes required at the server)

Answer (score 1):

well, an ISP knows if you have a tcp or udp connection, it might look into the packets and then knows if the connection is encrypted or not.

an ISP (which wants to disturb such encrypted connections) might start dropping packets. depending on the amount of dropped packets the connection then either dies or feels reaaaaaally slow and sluggish (coz tcp would have to reask the server to resend the (dropped) missing packets).

to find out if your ISP drops packets you have to use something like [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) might help you in detecting what is going on ( http://wiki.wireshark.org/PacketLoss ).

as mentioned in my comments to your question you might want to try putty. if this channel has connection problems caused by your ISP as well: bad luck. if putty / ssh works you might want to setup a SOCKS-proxy through ssh and see if that helps.

http://martinjr.net/2010/06/29/quick-and-easy-socks5-ssh-tunnel-set-up-with-putty/

Comment: it helped, is it normal that my connection through ssh is much slower than when I used the socks5?

Comment: well, when you put something in a box and wrap it in another box and in another box .. you can expect things to be a little bit wrapped up :) ( http://youtu.be/5Cx7jzq2Bx4?t=10s )

Comment: :) yeah but I guess its again the ISP doing their special service on port 22!

Comment: any way!, if I'm seeing the "blocked page", then socks is TCP and not encrypted, what can I do? any other proxy servers I can run on the VPS?

Comment: @Nig: you can change the ssh-port on your VSP as well... socks through ssh (putty) is encrypted. i am not sure if the DNS-queries from the browser are routed through the SOCKS as well ... if  they are resolved  from your ISP that might explain why you get "blocked" pages.

Comment: yeah, and maybe that's why it is slower.

Comment: is it definite compromise: speed or freedom ? :)

Comment: the issue is very strange, domains are resolved properly, a 403 error is received and the content is altered afterwards. (of course when using the the proxy)!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue as you mentioned and I found that the problems lies with the DNS server of your ISP.

I used my VPS to ping the server I wanted to access and I checked the IP that I am getting from the ping I am doing on my computer and they are completely different.

So I simply added that ip to my hosts file and viola! Done.

I didn't try and change the DNS servers on my network settings though. Thought it was too hassle

Comment: Set you DNS server as 8.8.8.8. Then install OpenDNS on your client machine. It uses TCP instead of UDP that your ISP could not simply modify you DNS response.